# add for loop inside jquery .after() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add `<option>` tag using for loop inside jquery .after() function.
I have the following code:

```
$("#myid").after("<!--more tags here-->"+
                  "<select class='form-control' name='dropdownmenu'>"+
                  "for (i=0; i < 4 ; i++){"+
                  "<option>i</option>}"+
                  "</select>"+
                  "<!--more tags here-->")
```

But that doesn't work, all I get is 1 `<option>` tag with the letter i inside

Comment: Your selector is wrong. I think you mean `$('#myid')` or `$('.myclass')`.

Comment: Sorry, a typo - fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not loop in js like that. you can something like following. You can create your select block first and then append it. code not tested, hopefully you get the idea.

```
var test = "<select class='form-control' name='dropdownmenu'>";

for (i=0; i < 4 ; i++){
    test += "<option>"+i+"</option>}";                  
}
test += "</select>";

$("#myid").after(test);  // note: use . for class or # for id
```

you can still add more tags this way:

```
$("#myid").after("<span>start</span>"+test+"<span>end</span>");
```

Comment: The problem is that in the actual code there are more tags added before and after the <select> tag, so I want only this specific block. I will try to edit the main post so it will be more clear.
**Sorry, . and # added together was a typo

Comment: Thank you, and last thing, I just noticed that for making the code here simpler, I changed an important piece, and your code works for the #id, but my actual code is using .class:last like that:
(.myclass : last).after()
What fix I can apply for that? I can't make it work with this little change

Comment: are you missing quotes? (".myclass : last").

Answer (score 0):

@techLove answer is valid.

But if you absolutely must, you can use `.map()` for that:

```
$("#myid").after("<!--more tags here-->"+
                  "<select class='form-control' name='dropdownmenu'>"+
                  [0, 1, 2, 3].map(i => "<option>"+i+"</option>") +
                  "</select>"+
                  "<!--more tags here-->")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question already has an answer, but, thanks to it, i've learned something new and i want to share this knowledge.

This way to do it, is, IMHO, cleaner and more elegant.

```js
var options = [0, 1, 2, 3];

$(function() {
  var $select = $('<select>', {
    class: 'form-control',
    name: 'dropdownmenu',
    html: options.map(function(option) {
      return $('<option>', {
        value: option,
        text: option
      })
    })
  }).appendTo('.wrapper');
  
  //if you really want to use after, remove "appendTo" and use this
  //$('.wrapper').after($select);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```